# Open FPDF in new tab

Tags: fpdf

I have a pdf generated (fpdf) from a post form. I would like the pdf to open in a new tab and/or window prompting the user to save the pdf. I'm guessing I need to save the output to a string

```
$data=$pdf->Output("OfficeForm.pdf", "S");
```

but what exactly can I do with this string to get it to open in a new window. I've attempted something like this but it's not working. Am I on the right track or is window.open not what I need?

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">      
window.open('$data', '_blank')    
</script>";
```

Comment: ...did you ever solve this issue? If so, could you please mark the correct answer or give your solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a form you can do it by specifying target='_blank' in the -tag (next to where you should have submit='something')

Example:

This will open a new Tab (showing whatever "makepdf.php" produces) on submit.

Hope it answers the question correctly

Comment: Haha so easy!
And with these lines:
`
    $pdf->Output($path . "filename.pdf', 'F');
    $pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I');
`
You can save it in the server and show it on the browser

Answer (score 1):

I simply added target="_blank" to my form opening tag and used $_SESSION[]; to pass my form to the FPDF code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form id ="buildPDFform" name="buildPDFform"  target="_blank" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

...some code for my form

<input type="submit" name="buildPDf" id="buildPDf" class="buildPDFbutton" value="Build the PDF">
</form>
```

Then when the form is submitted I gather my form items, put them in an array, create a session the array goes into and use a header("Location: testcode.php") to redirect to where my FPDF code is.

```
if (isset($_POST['buildPDf'])) {
    $pdfArray = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        ...gather your form items into your array

    }
    $_SESSION['pdfArray'] = $pdfArray;
    header("Location: testcode.php");
}
```

And don't forget in your FPDF code file (testcode.php in my case) to grab your session that has the array.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $pdfArray = $_SESSION['pdfArray'];

     ... your FPDF code

    $pdf->Output('I');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

source: https://www.thesitewizard.com/html-tutorial/open-links-in-new-window-or-tab.shtml

use **target="_blank"** in your **a** tag to open it to new tab

Answer (score 0):

Try `$pdf->Output("OfficeForm.pdf", "I");`

Comment: That works but opens it in the same window. Anyway to pass that to a new tab or window?

Comment: I guess you have a submit button on your form, which onclick submits the form and calls the php which generates the pdf.

Comment: Add to your script :

$('#submitbutton').click(function(){
     window.open('pdfexample.php');
 });

Comment: I suggest having 2 php files. One with the form and one with the fpdf generating. Than call the pdf generating php onclick with javascript, that will open your generated pdf in new tab. It worked for me.

Comment: I think this is the answer but just need to make sure I understand - the pdf uses $_POST data from the form. You're saying to have pdfexample.php (which generates the form) as window.open('pdfexample.php') and keep the form action to form_process.php? Does anything more need to be done to have the data pass to pdfexample.php correctly?

Comment: Yes, you need $_POST or $_GET to pass the data to pdf.

Comment: How do I use that $_POST in window.open()? Right now it just opens the window blank with no data passed.

Comment: Lets make it clear what you want. You have a Form, and you want it to be "printed" in a pdf after completing??