# Create PDF with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fpdf

I am using FPDF to create my report.

```
$pdf = new Report('P','mm','A4', $_POST);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Output('file.pdf','I');
```

And I use ajax to make requisition to the PHP.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../reports/report.php',
        data: { id: id }
    }).done(function(data){         
        window.open(data);           
    })
```

I want to show the report in a new tab

Comment: What is the question???

Comment: Not work, The question is clear. I need show one pdf after of to execute Ajax, but the return isn´t html.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837197/open-fpdf-in-new-tab

Comment: This question is different of stackoverflow.com/questions/26837197/open-fpdf-in-new-tab, because my FPDF it comes of ajax request e not one simple pdf file.

Comment: that question shows how to make what you are wanting to do, work.  Your thinking is a bit off on the logic-  you need to open the tab and 'pull' the info, not 'push' the tab open - see the link....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

I did the different way:

In my report PHP, I generate one temporay file, passing the parameter 'F'.

```
$pdf->Output('file.pdf','F');
```

In Jquery Ajax I opne the file, rather than open the data retorned of ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../reports/report.php',
        data: { id: id }
    }).done(function(data){         
        var fileName = "file.pdf";
        $('#modalRel').modal('show');
         var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
                    object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{FileName}\">here</a>";
                    object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                    object += "</object>";
                    object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "../Files/" + fileName);
                     $("#body-rel").html(object);
    })
```

I hope to have helped who one day to need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should success key. So it would be something like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../reports/report.php',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(data){
         var blob = new Blob([data]);
         window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
       }
    })
```

Comment: Not work. something like that appears:
%PDF-1.3

3 0 obj

<</Type /Page

/Parent 1 0 R

/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 429>>
stream
xï¿½ï¿½RMOï¿½0ï¿½ï¿½W<G8Ô±ï¿½[VZï¿½ï¿½Zï¿½d7.V (ï¿½YHï¿½ï¿½E;L;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ 8Ì‘ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½eBï¿½ï¿½ï¿½1ï¿½# ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½PnH*ï¿½ï¿½"&Eï¿½Cï¿½d8wï¿½ï¿½|*ï¿½,ï¿½ï¿½OQï¿½b^ï¿½#&D`2ï¿½
[ï¿½lfÈ»ï¿½ÌµÛºï¿½]kï¿½ï¿½ï¿½w;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½9ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½tð”¾’}Ë‘ï¿½ï¿½96ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½r
ï¿½"ï¿½#Nï¿½ï¿½ï¿½+ï¿½ï¿½7'ï¿½Üœ"ï¿½kï¿½ï¿½Aï¿½4lGï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Vï¿½Hï¿½d&